# Get all characters to end of line after identifying prefix characters iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a single raw string that prints as follows:

```
DCBNONE
DBA12292018
DCSJACKSON
DACJOHN
```

I need to pull the first name (DCS) and last name (DAC).

How do I pull these characters out by first identifying the prefix (DCS) and then grabbing all characters to the end of the line in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *dcsData;
NSString *dacData;

NSArray *lines = [theString componentsSeperatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterset newlineCharacterSet]];

for( NSString *line in lines )
{
  if( [line hasPrefix:@"DCS"] )
  {
     dcsData = [line substringFromIndex:3];
  }
  if( [line hasPrefix:@"DAC"] )
  {
     dacData = [line substringFromIndex:3];
  }
}
```

Typped in Safari.